# It's bobo time. What's the meaning?

Tags: meaning, expressions, slang

I saw this sentence at the end of an internet article:

> It's bobo time.

Meaning that the author wanted to take his leave now. But what is "bobo" in "bobo time"? Something like bed time? What is the origin of this expression?

Comment: It might help if you gave us a link to the rest of the article.

Comment: The article is partly in Indonesian, but the author is an English speaker.I don't understand why it's off topic. It's a learner question, and an expression (I've found it several time on the Internet, but couldn't figure the proper meaning)

Comment: Did you read the [Details, Please meta post](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please)? It explains the importance of providing context and prior research. Add those to your question – with an edit, not a comment  – and your question can be reopened.

Comment: I had the reply, so it's ok. But the context is not always possible. Here I would have to translate a text that is half-English half-Indonesian.

Comment: Context is not always exact text from an article. You don't even tell us what the article is about, or (perhaps more significantly) the tone of it. Is it a humorous article? A political news piece? And there's probably more English text than "It's bobo time." In any event, it sounds like it might be a play on words (similar phonetically to "It's bye-bye time"), but that's just a guess.

Comment: It's actually (somewhat archaic) Br Eng baby talk for time to go to sleep - "time for bo-boes"

Answer (score 3):

It's just a song sung by DJ Bobo.

1Time To Turn Off The Light

Now it’s time to turn off the light

Now it’s time to — say goodbye

Planet colors is coming back

Once again — someday...